# Wrong fit using scipy curve_fit

Tags: python, numpy, scipy, curve-fitting

I am trying to fit some data to a power law function with exponential cut off. I generate some data with numpy and i am trying to fit those data with scipy.optimization. 
Here is my code:

```
import numpy as np
from scipy.optimize import curve_fit

def func(x, A, B, alpha):
    return A * x**alpha * np.exp(B * x)

xdata = np.linspace(1, 10**8, 1000)
ydata = func(xdata, 0.004, -2*10**-8, -0.75)
popt, pcov = curve_fit(func, xdata, ydata)
print popt
```

The result of I am getting is: [1, 1, 1] which does not correspond with the data.
¿Am i doing something wrong?

Comment: My method breaks because your final data point (at 655642210) has a value of 0. When you take the log of it you get a NaN. I've computed the fit using my method excluding that point and get something that looks reasonable A = 0.00326, alpha = -0.767, B = -1.88e-8

Comment: Yes you are right! Ive noticed my mistake and deleted mi second cuestion. Thank you so much

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Whilst xnx gave you the answer as to why `curve_fit` failed here I thought I'd suggest a different way of approaching the problem of fitting your functional form which doesn't rely on a gradient descent (and therefore a reasonable initial guess)

Note that if you take the log of the function that you are fitting you get the form

[image: \log f = \log A + \alpha \log x + B x]

Which is linear in each of the unknown parameters (log A, alpha, B)

We can therefore use the machinery of linear algebra to solve this by writing the equation in the form of a matrix as

log y = M p

Where log y is a column vector of the log of your ydata points, p is a column vector of the unknown parameters and M is the matrix `[[1], [log x], [x]]`

Or explicitly

[image]

The best fitting parameter vector can then be found efficiently by using [`np.linalg.lstsq`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.linalg.lstsq.html)

Your example problem in code could then be written as

```
import numpy as np

def func(x, A, B, alpha):
    return A * x**alpha * np.exp(B * x)

A_true = 0.004
alpha_true = -0.75
B_true = -2*10**-8

xdata = np.linspace(1, 10**8, 1000)
ydata = func(xdata, A_true, B_true, alpha_true)

M = np.vstack([np.ones(len(xdata)), np.log(xdata), xdata]).T

logA, alpha, B = np.linalg.lstsq(M, np.log(ydata))[0]

print "A =", np.exp(logA)
print "alpha =", alpha
print "B =", B
```

Which recovers the initial parameters nicely:

```
A = 0.00400000003736
alpha = -0.750000000928
B = -1.9999999934e-08
```

Also note that this method is around 20x faster than using `curve_fit` for the problem at hand

```
In [8]: %timeit np.linalg.lstsq(np.vstack([np.ones(len(xdata)), np.log(xdata), xdata]).T, np.log(ydata))
10000 loops, best of 3: 169 µs per loop


In [2]: %timeit curve_fit(func, xdata, ydata, [0.01, -5e-7, -0.4])
100 loops, best of 3: 4.44 ms per loop
```

Answer (score 2):

Apparently your initial guess (which defaults to `[1,1,1]`, since you didn't give one -- see [the docs](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-0.16.0/reference/generated/scipy.optimize.curve_fit.html)) is too far from the actual parameters to allow the algorithm to converge. The main problem is probably with `B` which, if positive, will send your exponential function to very large values for your provided `xdata`.

Try providing something a little closer to the actual parameters and it works:

```
p0 = 0.01, -5e-7, -0.4    # Initial guess for the parameters
popt, pcov = curve_fit(func, xdata, ydata, p0)
print popt
```

Output:

```
[  4.00000000e-03  -2.00000000e-08  -7.50000000e-01]
```